# Change of the number of solutions when squaring the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm solving a quiz and there is a question where I can't decide between two answers:
Let $Ax = b$ be a system of equations with a square matrix $A$. Which of the following is true? (the other 2 are nonsense)

a) If $Ax = b$ has exactly one solution, so does $(A \cdot A)x = b$.

b) If $Ax = b$ doesn't have any solution, same applies for $(A \cdot A)x = b$.

It's easy to prove that once a matrix is regular, no power of it can make it singular. Yes it makes sense but what about b). I can't magically make the matrix contain $b$ in it's image or can I?

Comment: If $Ay=b$ has no solution neither does $(A \cdot A)x = A(Ax)=b$ since if it did $y=Ax$ would solve the former.

Comment: "A has one solution" iff "det(A) is nonzero" and squaring can never make a determinant zero. As for the second, it is conceivable for Ax = b to have no solutions but A^2 x = b to have one. Let A be rotation by 90 degrees and b = -x. Ax = b has no solutions but A^2 x = b does (why?)

Comment: @BalancedTryteOperators It is impossible for $Ax = b$ to have no solutions but $A^2 x = b$ to have one. Note that when given the equation $Ax = b$, we are meant to assume that $b$ is a constant-vector, independent of $x$.

Comment: I see that. But the problem is that the teacher is presenting this as "a xor b" which means b) must have a different interpretation from a) (or he or she should be fired). If they have the same interpretation, then why would he or she put this on a multiple choice test?

Answer (score 0):

About (a): Since $Ax=b$ has exactly one solution, the kernel of $A$ is equal to $\{0\}$.
But then $A$ is invertible. But then also $A^2$ is invertible, and $A^2x =b$ has exactly one solution.

The difference between (a) and (b) is the quantification 'exactly one' in (a) and 'no solution' (which is the negation of 'there is at least one') in (b).

Comment: I don't get it. Both seem right.

Comment: What exactly? Can you be more specific, so I can expand the answer. Are you familiar with rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: What is the outcome of your answer? I need to know which of them is right. Yes, a) is right for sure but what about b)? I can't find any way of disproving b).

Comment: That is already answered in the first comment by Conifold.

Comment: So the Conifold's comment says b) is true and you say a) is true?

Comment: yes...................

Comment: Well, that's disappointing. Only one should be true! That's why I'm confused.